# AJAX return data fade into existing elements

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

On my website I have an update form that when submitted alters my database. 
What I want to do however is have all the elements that contain the old values,

***AJAX***

```
// UPDATE 
     $(".bill-upd-submit").click(function() {
          var elem = $(this);
          $.post("update_bill.php", elem.parent(".bill-upd").serialize(), function(data) {
             //INSERT INTO OLD VALUES
          });
    });
```

***PHP***

In my PHP I've tried the following with no luck, has anybody done this before or can give me advice on where I may be going wrong?

```
 echo "elem.closest('li').find('.cost').html('');";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to have the server provide the jQuery code. You can just type it into the callback function, where you have your `//INSERT INTO OLD VALUES`-comment.

```
$.post("update_bill.php", elem.parent(".bill-upd").serialize(), function(data) {
  //We will use the "data"-variable that was passed to this function by jQuery.
  elem.closest('li').find('.cost').html(data);
});
```

In the above code, the "data"-variable contains that which was given back by the server. So for that solution, make sure that `"update_bill.php"` will return the HTML that you want to insert into `'li .cost'`.

Comment: Thanks @Avaq I have multiple things I want to return however and they all need to go into different elements and at the moment theyre all going into .cost, is it possible to split this?

Comment: Yes. If you have full control over the answer that your server gives, you can just return [JSON](http://nl.php.net/json_encode). In that case the "data" variable will contain the JSON element that you returned, and you can do with it whatever you want. This method works together pretty well with [clientside templating](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/).

Comment: Alternatively, when you receive the different elements in one big HTML file, you can use jQuery to select the sub-elements from there, like so: `var myMenu = $(data).find('#menu')`, etc.

Comment: How do I go about splitting the JSON element up? Sorry this is my first time working with AJAX and im not even sure what to type into Google @Avaq

Comment: Ok, first of all you have to be sure that the server actually returns JSON. If it does, jQuery will recognise that for you, and put it into that "data"-variable. From there you have the JSON element that was returned by your server. JSON elements are basically arrays with named keys. So you can use the data inside them for anything. If you don't know how to work with JSON, yet you want to learn - I suggest you find some Jquery Ajax and JSON tutorials :)